# RXJS - subscribing to the Server side event on first subscribe, unsubscribe on last unsubscribe and resubscribe on next subscribe

Tags: rxjs

I have a front end with Server Side events and multiple places where I want to subscribe to it.

I want to subscribe to the server-side event once, and also unsubscribe when no one observes it.

I'm not sure how to accomplish that with rxjs.

Here's a walkthrough of what I want:

1. X subscribes

   - result => Connect to Server Side Event
2. Y Subscribe

   - result => Listen to the same server-side event
3. X unsubscribe

   - result => nothing
4. Y unsubscribe

   - result => Disconnect from Server Side Event
5. Z subscribes

   - result => Connection to Server Side Event again

I've played with defer, and new Observable etc... but feel like I'm not on the right path

Comment: `share` operator ? https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/share

Comment: @EddyLin is right, you're looking for `share()` with `resetOnRefCountZero = true`

Comment: @EddyLin seems like that's exactly what I was looking for - thanks.

Comment: @EddyLin - do you want to post our comment as the answer, and get the score for it?

Comment: @Noam It's fine,I'm glad to help.  : )